# Why is Project Wonderful mostly only used for web comics?

Tags: advertising

I've looked a few times at placing ads on my site, but the only ad system I've liked is [Project Wonderful](http://www.projectwonderful.com). The problem with it is that almost every existing publisher(and thus, probably advertiser) is web comics. My website isn't related to web comics.

So, is there a reason that it's used almost exclusively by web comics, or was that just what's happened so far? Or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Project Wonderful's [CEO Ryan North](https://www.projectwonderful.com/about.php) is a comics creator himself, and it probably started out as a tool for himself and other comic sites. For a definitive answer, you'll have to ask him.

On the other hand, running a [search](https://www.projectwonderful.com/adsearch.php) for every category *except* the comics ones gave me 4600+ results. (I'd put an actual link in here except that the resulting URL seems to not-quite-valid and gets stripped.) Putting the comics categories back in about doubles that. So yes, a lot, but definitely not "most." As to whether that 4600-ish is enough for you, you'll have to decide.

Comment: Ah, I searched a few years ago. I guess I should've searched before putting in this question